# R: download all files in a Google Drive public folder

Tags: r, download, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get data for RAIS (a Brazilian employee registry dataset) that is shared using a Google Drive public folder. This is the address:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByKsqUnItyBhZmNwaXpnNXBHMzQ&usp=sharing&tid=0ByKsqUnItyBhU2RmdUloTnJGRGM#list

Data is divided into one folder per year and within each folder there is one file per state to download. I would like to automate the downloading process in R, for all years, and if not at least within each year folder. Downloaded file names should follow the file names that occur when downloading manually.

A know a little R, but no web programming or web scraping. This is what I got so faar:
By manually downloading the first of the 2012 file, I could see the URL my browser used to download:
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0ByKsqUnItyBhS2RQdFJ2Q0RrN0k&export=download

Thus, I suppose the file id is: 0ByKsqUnItyBhS2RQdFJ2Q0RrN0k

Searching the html code of the 2012 page I was able to find that ID and the file name associated with it: AC2012.7z.
All the other ids' and file names are in that section of the html code. So, assuming I can download the file correctly, I suppose I could at least generalize tho the other files.

In R, I tried the flowing code to download the file:

```
url <- "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0ByKsqUnItyBhS2RQdFJ2Q0RrN0k&export=download"
download.file(url,"AC2012.7z")
unzip("AC2012.7z")
```

It does download but I get and error when trying to uncompress the file (both within R and manually with 7.zip) There must be something wrong with file downloaded in R, as the the file size (3.412Kb) does not match what I get from manualy downloading the file (3.399Kb)

Comment: http://thebiobucket.blogspot.ie/2014/03/download-all-documents-from-google.html

Comment: @jdharrison : tks. Here is a little different, because the main folder is public, and the documentation on RGoogleDocs  does not mention that. But  I'll look at to code to see.

Comment: Why dont you copy the whole folder to your own drive,  and then bulk download the files?

Comment: @user3616725: no, I'm trying to wrap it in a function to make downloading and working with this data easy. So I can not assume the user has a google account

Comment: @LucasMation have u found out any solution?

Comment: @Shashank, no. (they changed to a ftp server which solved my problem)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to solve this problem today, you can use the [`googledrive` package](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/index.html).

```
library(googledrive)
ls_tibble <- googledrive::drive_ls(GOOGLE_DRIVE_URL_FOR_THE_TARGET_FOLDER)
for (file_id in ls_tibble$id) {
  googledrive::drive_download(as_id(file_id))
}
```

This will (1) trigger an authentication page to open in your browser to authorise the Tidyverse libraries using `gargle` to access Google Drive on behalf of your account and (2) download all the files in the folder at that URL to your current working directory for the current R session.

Comment: I find it a bit alarming that googledrive wants write permission on my Google drive just so I can download a public file. I run this code to give it read.only access: `googledrive::drive_auth(scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly", email="<youremail@gmail.com>")`