# Download all files of a folder from a Google Drive directory from R

Tags: r, google-drive-api

I have one folder by customer shared with me in google drive. I want download one specific folder to put the name in the files .xlsx with the same name of folder. I have the code bellow:

```
#load the libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(googledrive)

#folder link to id
jp_folder = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M79U45FfFlimkguyuh74557"
folder_id = drive_get(as_id(jp_folder))

#find files in folder
files = drive_ls(folder_id)
```

when I run: `files = drive_ls(folder_id)` pops up:

```
Error: Client error: (404) Not Found Shared drive not found: 0AM_QUGgk4cU9UXXHFJ

domain: global
reason: notFound
message: Shared drive not found: 0AM_QUGgk4cU9UXXHFJ
locationType: parameter
location: driveId
```

does anyone know why this error?

Comment: Is this will help ?[R: download all files in a Google Drive public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149700/r-download-all-files-in-a-google-drive-public-folder)